# Can I show bullets with sub-bullets incrementally using quarto and revealjs

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

With revealjs and quarto I can make an incremental bullet with `.incremental` but is there a way to tell it to reveal sub-bullets with the bullets at the same time?  For example in this code:

```
---
title: "Demo"
format: revealjs
---

::: incremental
- thingy 1
    - detail 1A
    - detail 1B
- thingy 2
    - detail 2A
    - detail 2B
:::
```

I want detail 1A and detail 1B to appear with thingy 1 and then I want detail 2A and detail 2B to appear with thingy 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`fragment`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#fragments) to merge the subbullets to the main bullet and show them separately like this:

```
---
title: "Demo"
format: revealjs
---

::: {.fragment}
- thingy 1
    - detail 1A
    - detail 1B
:::
::: {.fragment}
- thingy 2
    - detail 2A
    - detail 2B
:::
```

Output:

[image]